# Ubuntu-equivalent of Suse Studio?

Tags: customization, custom-distributions

Is there an Ubuntu-equivalent of [Suse Studio](https://susestudio.com/)? I haven't been able to find anything, but there may be something hiding in the web...

I'm looking for an equivalent - with options such as being able to publicly publish your customised distro; on the site.

Comment: For this question to work you probably need to explain what Suse Studio is. Or can we assume you are asking about https://ubuntustudio.org/

Comment: May be [Ubuntu Customization Kit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/uck/) and [The Live Systems](http://live.debian.net/)(for Debian)..?

Comment: The debian live scripts are most reliable, but not graphical or web based.

Comment: I'd like to know too! I have to prepare two ubuntu installs and don't want to install the same packages on two machines twice! I'd also like to avoid changing setting twice...

Answer (score 1):

There is a Good One called Cubic, And here is a Good Tutorial for it, to!

Tutorial - https://www.ostechnix.com/create-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image/